# CSS for Previous and Next

Tags: html, css

I am developing pages for which there are previous and next buttons. Right now it is using a table where the first column (td) is the "previous" button, the second column is the text, and the third column is the "next" button. The middle column has a lot of text (many pages worth) and the user scrolls down to view the entirety of the text. Here is my current HTML snippet:

```
<table><tr>
 <td class="prevnext" id="prev"></td>
 <td>
  <div id="maintext"></div>
  <div id="footnotes"></div>
 </td>
 <td class="prevnext" id="next"></td>
</tr></table>
```

JavaScript populates the fields, and it works fine... from a layout perspective, it puts a < for the previous page and a > for the next page. I want the < and > to always be centered in relation to the text, even when the user scrolls down. Right now it's centered to the text in an absolute fashion so one would have to scroll down to the middle of the text to actually see the < and > buttons.

Is there a way to make those buttons "float" so that however the user scrolls down they are always centered vertically on the page?

Also, here is the current CSS I have (very simple):

```
.prevnext {
 cursor:pointer;
 background-color:#eee;
}
```

If the only way to accomplish it is using JavaScript, I can work that out on my own. But I'm of the philosophy that JavaScript shouldn't be used to do something that is inherent within CSS.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q8buLh7/).

Comment: Is it important that you use this tabular structure? It would be much easier to simply use `position:fixed` and have the prev/next buttons 'follow' the user down the page that way.

Comment: something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/6q8buLh7/1/)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all, I wouldn't recommend using tables for layout, but it is irrelevant to the solution. Just a note.

Objects can be placed in a fixed position on the screen with `position: fixed;`.

use:

```
foobar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hyyLwoLx/

Comment: Just what I was looking for. I also generally agree with modern recommendations that using tables for layout should have been left in the 1990's. But I wasn't sure how else to approach this particular thing.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to have a `flex` layout. You can make following changes to your CSS.

```
tr {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Give class to `tr` if there are more such elements.

Comment: You may want to mention browser compatibility issues with this approach: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox.

Comment: And the Previous and next sections are not fixed in place: http://jsfiddle.net/jas6guqb/